# Adding a string between some pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I would like to add the string "AND" between the words "STREET" and "HENRY" into the following string:

`WEST 156 STREET HENRY HUDSON PARKWAY`

So that it reads `WEST 156 STREET AND HENRY HUDSON PARKWAY`. Essentially, I am trying to geocode intersections so I would like to be able to add "AND" between street types (AVENUE, STREET, BLVD, etc.) and whatever word comes after that to create the intersection like I specified above.

Here are a couple more examples (just made up):

```
strings = c("WEST 135TH AVE BROADWAY", # want WEST 135TH AVE AND BROADWAY,
"SUNSET BLVD MAIN ST", # SUNSET BLVD AND MAIN ST
"W 45TH ST LAKESHORE BLVD", #...
"HIGH ST BROAD ST") # ...
```

I would greatly appreciate any help! I am somewhat familiar with regular expressions, but I am not familiar with how to insert another word in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

capture the words as a group and replace with backreference (`\\1`) along with the substring "AND".  For the third and fourth strings, as it is at the end of the string, it wouldn't replace as we used `\\s+` (one or more spaces)

```
sub("(AVENUE|AVE|STREET|BLVD)\\s+", "\\1 AND ", strings)
```

-output

```
[1] "WEST 135TH AVE AND BROADWAY" "SUNSET BLVD AND MAIN ST"    
[3] "W 45TH ST LAKESHORE BLVD"    "HIGH ST BROAD ST"
```